# Cartoon with girl on a wheelchair and a genie as helper against an evil entity

Tags: story-identification, magic, cartoon

I remember watching a cartoon as a child, in the 80s or early 90s and I can't remember the title (or a lot of details about it). The setting reminds me of "Nadia: The Secret of Blue Water": we could be at the end of the 19th century, but my memory does not support me much in this.

Anyways, the protagonist of the cartoon is a girl on a wheelchair who is supported by a female genie wearing "One Thousand and One Nights" clothes. The genie protects the little girl from the assaults of the minions of an evil entity; in the first episode of the series the minions disguise themselves as workers of a circus just arrived in the town where the little girl lives. For some reasons I do not remember, the evil entity wants to terminate the little girl.

At the end of each episode the minions are inevitably defeated by the magic of the genie and the evil entity transforms them in little worms, for eternal punishment. The worms retain the original heads (so they continue to talk to the evil entity) and live in a rocky-bowl next to their master.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds a bit like [Clémentine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cl%C3%A9mentine), fits on your description quite well: Girl on a wheelchair, has a magical companion, and aired on the approximate time you mentioned (1990).

Quoting Wikipedia:

> Clémentine is the daughter of a famous French pilot and war hero Alex Dumat, who raised her alone with her brother Petit Boy. After she lost the use of her legs in an airplane accident, she travels the world with her family to find a cure that will allow her to walk again. Meanwhile, in her nightly dreams, she can walk and her cat Hélice (French for "propeller") can talk and fly with the help of a helicopter-like apparatus on its head. Clementine leads a battle against the demon Malmoth, with the guidance of her guardian angel Héméra, travelling in a magical blue sphere. Occasionally, in these travels through fantasy and time, she meets famous fictional characters such as Pinocchio, Aladdin and Oliver Twist. She also frequently meets historic characters, especially aviation pioneers such as Charles Lindbergh, and Kateri Tekakwitha.

Comment: That's Clementine, indeed. Thank you very much for your help.