# 70s-90s animated series about a girl in a wheelchair and her guardian lady

Tags: story-identification, animated-series

I remember an animated series from the mid nineties of a girl who is in a wheelchair and gets visited by a lady in a small bubble who could be considered as her guardian angel, this bubble gets bigger and this girl walks into it and goes to have many adventures.

I do not remember that part well, but her foe is a really terrifying demon, even for an adult, made of fire who tries to catch the bubble but can't do anything to it and turns some people into vermines and other lower life forms when they fail.

I'm assuming it is from the late 70s to early 90s but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Clementine's Enchanted Journey* (1985).

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0297529/):

> The teen daughter of an air combat pilot travels around the world to find the cure for her injury, due to which she cannot walk but seeing precognitive dreams she can foretell the future only if she could deliver their meanings.

---

Found by searching this site for `[story-identification] wheelchair` which returned, among others, [Cartoon with girl on a wheelchair and a genie as helper against an evil entity](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/65960).